# OMath buildup() escaped characters

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to write an equation to Word via the OMath namespace, but I can't get escaped characters to generate properly. When I execute the console program below, it properly places the numerator and divisor, but the escaped character "\delta", remains exactly as typed in, rather than turning into the greek symbol for lowercase delta.

If I set the cursor just after the 'a' in \delta, and press space, it converts. If I click *Professional* from the ribbon, also converts.

Can someone explain how to create an escaped character programmatically, and get it to display properly?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fName = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Doc_1.docx";

        Word._Application myApp = new Word.Application();
        myApp.Visible = true;

        Word.Document myDoc = myApp.Documents.Open(fName);

        Word.Range myFunctionR = myApp.Selection.OMaths.Add(myApp.Selection.Range);
        Word.OMathFunction myFunction = myApp.Selection.OMaths[1].Functions.Add(
            myApp.Selection.Range, Word.WdOMathFunctionType.wdOMathFunctionBox);
        Word.OMathBox myBox = myFunction.Box;

        myBox.E.Range.Text = @"\delta = (PL)/(AE)";
        myBox.E.BuildUp();
    }
```

If I paste out the MathML from MS Word, it looks like this:

**Correct/Desired Version:**

```
<mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math">
<mml:mi>δ</mml:mi><mml:mi> 
<mml:mi> </mml:mi>
<mml:mo>=</mml:mo>
<mml:mfrac>
    <mml:mrow>
        <mml:mi>P</mml:mi>
        <mml:mi>L</mml:mi>
    </mml:mrow>
    <mml:mrow>
        <mml:mi>A</mml:mi>
        <mml:mi>E</mml:mi>
        </mml:mrow>
</mml:mfrac>
```

**Incorrect/Programmatic Version:**

```
<mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math">
<mml:mo>\</mml:mo>
<mml:mi>d</mml:mi>
<mml:mi>e</mml:mi>
<mml:mi>l</mml:mi>
<mml:mi>t</mml:mi>
<mml:mi>a</mml:mi>
<mml:mi> </mml:mi>
<mml:mo>=</mml:mo>
<mml:mfrac>
    <mml:mrow>
        <mml:mi>P</mml:mi>
        <mml:mi>L</mml:mi>
    </mml:mrow>
    <mml:mrow>
        <mml:mi>A</mml:mi>
        <mml:mi>E</mml:mi>
        </mml:mrow>
</mml:mfrac>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it, 2 years later... The following method converts the input escaped text into a properly formatted equation. Then when OMath.Buildup() is called, it is able to properly format the equation as one would expect.

Note on the question: I was originally going down a MathML path, which isnt necessarily bad, but was a tangent from my original goal. This route uses Word's built in equation autocorrect (fancy find and replace) to generate the correct UTF Coded characters.

```
private string OMathAutoCorrect(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return null;
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.OMathAutoCorrect.UseOutsideOMath = true;
        var retString = input;
        foreach (OMathAutoCorrectEntry ac in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.OMathAutoCorrect.Entries)
        {
            if (retString.Contains(ac.Name))
            {
                var matchIndex = retString.IndexOf(ac.Name);
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                //Capture all data prior to the match:
                sb.Append(retString.Substring(0, matchIndex));
                //Add the Match
                sb.Append(ac.Value);
                //Capture all data after the match:
                var indexAfterMatch = matchIndex + ac.Name.Length;
                var remLength = retString.Length - indexAfterMatch;
                sb.Append(retString.Substring(indexAfterMatch, remLength));
                retString = sb.ToString();

            }
            Debug.WriteLine($"{ac.Name}, {ac.Value}, Char#: {ac.Value.Length}");
        }

        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.OMathAutoCorrect.UseOutsideOMath = false;
        return retString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For replacing alphabets use following code

var script = @"\delta = (PL)/(AE)";

script = script.Replace("\delta", "\u03B4");}

You will have to identify all the Greek alphabets and replace with the equivalent UTF16 code.

Please find the below website for list of available aphabets
https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm